# Securing REST API for Heroku

Tags: mysql, express, ssl, heroku, https

I have deployed an Angular Node.js web app on Heroku but have run into an issue with grabbing data from my server/db.

I have a linux server hosted by Vultr that contains a MySQL db. On this server I have created a REST api using express to grab the data from the db. The issue I'm running into is on my site at heroku is that I find the following in the console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com/' was loaded
> over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://my-server-ip:3000/endpoint-name'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How would I go about securing my REST api? I have looked into getting SSL certificates but they require a domain name to work? My api uses the IP:Port for the express app so no domain is involved.

I'm very new to this so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When loading the webpage in HTTPS, the XMLHttpRequest required to be in HTTPS. In order to achieve HTTPS or SSL Certificate, you must need a qualified domain name. It is no longer possible to get SSL certificate for IP addresses. To get rid of the error either you  can load the webpage in HTTP or get a domain with SSL certificate.